# How to display Images that are in a ts table

Tags: angular, image, display

I am trying to display from html file images that are in a table in .ts.

Here is my table:

```js
BHs = [
  new Bh (1, "src/assets/img/photo_bonhommes/BH1.jpg"),
  new Bh (2, "src/assets/img/photo_bonhommes/BH2.png"),
  new Bh (3, "src/assets/img/photo_bonhommes/BH3.png"),
  new Bh (4, "src/assets/img/photo_bonhommes/BH4.png"),
  new Bh (5, "src/assets/img/photo_bonhommes/BH5.png"),
  new Bh (6, "src/assets/img/photo_bonhommes/BH6.png"),
  new Bh (7, "src/assets/img/photo_bonhommes/BH7.png"),
  new Bh (8, "src/assets/img/photo_bonhommes/BH8.png"),
  new Bh (9, "src/assets/img/photo_bonhommes/BH9.png"),
  new Bh (10, "src/assets/img/photo_bonhommes/BH10.png"),
  new Bh (11, "src/assets/img/photo_bonhommes/BH11.png"),
];
```

With the class :

```js
 export class Bh {
  constructor(
    id: number,
    src: String,
  ){}
 }
```

And here is my html line :

```html
<img id="bh" routerLink="/" *ngFor="let bh of BHs" src="bh.src"/> 
{{bh.src}}
```

I've seen people with the same problem, so I tried :

```html
<img id="bh" routerLink="/" *ngFor="let bh of BHs" src="bh.src"/>

<img id="bh" routerLink="/" *ngFor="let bh of BHs" src="{bh.src}"/>

<div *ngFor="let bh of BHs">
    <img id="bh" routerLink="/" [src]='bh.src'/>
</div>
```

But none worked..

So I am a bit lost, I could use some help?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't with the image binding, your class isn't defined properly, in your code if you simply `console.log(BHs)`, you will get empty objects with no data, therefore `bh.src` is undefined

Declare your class like this:

```
 export class Bh {
  constructor(
    id: number,
    src: String,
  ){
      Object.assign(this, {id:id, src:src});
   }
 }
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-muwcdm?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: Thank you very much, it first didn't work with my last html line verison, but it worked with 
<div *ngFor="let bh of BHs">
    <img id="bh" routerLink="/" [src]='bh.src'/>
</div> 
Thank you !!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use syntax like this -

```
<img id="bh" routerLink="/" *ngFor="let bh of BHs" [src]="bh?.src" />
```

Comment: This also works, added to Adrita's solution, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use DomSanitizer;

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';  
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer){

    this.imgSrc = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(yourSrc);
}
```

Comment: I don't get it, what do I put in "imgSrc" and "yourSrc" since I have 11 photos so 11 sources ? Thank you for your answer btw

Comment: maybe with ``` for(let item in BHs){item. imgSrc = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(item. imgSrc);}``` . and I'm not sure about  that it was because of the safeUrl. You can check the src on HTML, was it unsafe or not.

Comment: I finally had a solution, but thank you for answering !

Answer (score 0):

When you pass this element :

```
new Bh (1, "src/assets/img/photo_bonhommes/BH1.jpg"), etc…
```

and then you call it in your template, is like doing this :

```
<img id="bh" routerLink="/" *ngFor="let bh of BHs" src="src/assets/img/photo_bonhommes/BH1.jpg"/>
```

So maybe you should remove the excessive `src` and just put `/assets/img/photo_bonhommes/….jpg`

You can try this:

```
<img [id]="bh.id" routerLink="/" *ngFor="let bh of BHs" [src]="bh.src"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, I had my solution !